# Disable tcp connections after a certain number of clients have connected.

Tags: tcp

We are running Linux and have a Ruby application that needs to accept exactly 4 connections and then not accept any more until one of the clients drops off. The reason I ask this here is there should be a way to tell the kernel "stop listing on this port until I tell you otherwise". How would I do that?

Comment: In some sense, it might be reasonable to implement the limit in the application itself. While `iptables` can limit the number of tcp connections, your application knows the state of the connections better, and can apply the limitation to e.g. authenticated or non-authenticated connections only.

Answer (score 3):

The `connlimit` module of `iptables` would be one way:

```
iptables  -A  INPUT  -p  tcp  --syn  --dport 12345  -m   connlimit
          --connlimit-above 4 -j REJECT
```